# node.js with express - showing custom error message

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node.js and express and I want to show custom error message when the requested page is not found. Currently I am doing it by using a Wildcards. If any of the routes doesn't match then the last route gets invoked. **Is there any other better way to do this??**

> My routes

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/hello', hello.hello);
app.get('/*', error.error);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is good. The only thing I would change is the order of routes like so

```
 app.get('/users', user.list);
 app.get('/hello', hello.hello);
 app.get('/', routes.index);
 app.get('/*', error.error);
```

A good rule to follow is define all least general routes first. As you probably know this basically tells express that if no other route is found show an error message and wild cards are a pretty good way to do it.